# Test if ICommand was executed

Tags: wpf, mocking, icommand

My questions is the following: how can I test if an ICommand's Execute method was called on a mock object ?

I'm using the following code:

```
var mockOperandVM = new Mock<UCOperandViewModel> ();  
mockOperandVM.Setup (x => x.EditCommand).Returns (new RelayCommand<String> (x => { }));  

var toolbarTrayVM = new UCToolbarTrayViewModel (mockComponentsLocator.Object);
toolbarTrayVM.EditCommand.Execute ("Edit");
mockOperandVM.Verify (x => x.EditCommand.Execute ("Edit"), "EditCommand with 'Edit' parameter was not executed on the mock object.");
```

I have to specify here that I have an EditCommand ICommand on the UCOperandViewModel too and I want to test whether that ICommand gets executed when I call EditCommand.Execute on the toolbarTrayVM.

I get an ArgumentException on the call to Verify. It says that "A matching constructor for the given arguments was not found on the mocked type.".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please provide more code? How are you using the ICommand, sample test code and what are you trying to test.

Comment: Which mocking framework are you using (if any)?

Answer (score 1):

Inject the service into the [SUT](http://xunitpatterns.com/SUT.html) - preferably using **Constructor Injection**. That would enable you to write unit test code like this:

```
var mock = new Mock<IService>();

var sut = new MyViewModel(mock.Object);
sut.SomeCommand.Execute(null);

mock.Verify(s => s.Foo());
```

This example uses [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/).

Comment: Can you give more details? What is IService? Foo()?

Comment: it is a dependency interface, service for db. you need to mock it to be able to inject your viewmodel.